# Ubuntu 16.04 Display Setting while Ubuntu 18.4 scalling is missing, Where is the Scalling?

Tags: display, display-manager, scaling, menu-bar

[Here I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I can adjust the scaling. In 18.4 LTS the scaling is missing?????](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKyM9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu switched from the Unity desktop to the Gnome Shell Desktop. Scaling works differently in Gnome Desktop than it did in Unity.

- You can set overall scaling, but only by integers (i.e. 100%, 200%) in Settings - Displays
- You can further adjust font scaling after installing Gnome Tweaks by changing "Scaling factor" on the Fonts tab.